# Set a discounted cart item price that is reflected on Orders in Woocommerce 3

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, checkout, orders, discount

I use this code in my functions.php to apply a 10% discount on my products, starting from the 2nd one in the cart:

```
function add_discount_price_percent( $cart_object ) {

    global $woocommerce;

    $pdtcnt=0;

    foreach ($woocommerce->cart->get_cart() as $cart_item_key => $cart_item) {
        $pdtcnt++;

        $oldprice = 0;
        $newprice = 0;


        if($pdtcnt>1) { // from second product

            $oldprice = $cart_item['data']->price; //original product price      

            // echo "$oldprice<br />";

            $newprice = $oldprice*0.9; //discounted price
            $cart_item['data']->set_sale_price($newprice);
            $cart_item['data']->set_price($newprice);
            $cart_item['data']->set_regular_price($oldprice);

        }     
    }

    WC()->cart->calculate_totals();

}


add_action( 'woocommerce_before_cart', 'add_discount_price_percent', 1);

add_action( 'woocommerce_before_checkout_form', 'add_discount_price_percent', 99 );
```

Prices are displayed correctly both in the cart and in the checkout page, but when I test my payment with PayPal sandbox I see and must pay the full price because the discount is ignored.

If I echo the discount prices just before the submit button I get the correct prices:

```
function echo_discount_before_checkout_submit() {

    if ( is_admin() && ! defined( 'DOING_AJAX' ) )
        return;

    foreach ( WC()->cart->get_cart() as $key => $value ) {
        echo $value['data']->price . "<br />";
    }

}
add_action( 'woocommerce_review_order_before_submit', 'echo_discount_before_checkout_submit', 99 );
```

How can I send the correct, discounted prices to PayPal?

EDIT: @LoisTheAtzec reply is really good but I need to get a 10% discount even on first product if quantity is over 2: I'm trying this code but I can't get correct values.

```
// If it is the first product and quantity is over 1
if ($count === 1 && $cart_item['quantity'] >= 2) {

        // get unit price
        $unit_price = $cart_item['data']->get_price();

        // get quantity to discount (total - 1)
        $discounted_quantity = $cart_item['quantity'] - 1;

        // get total discount amount (on total quantity - 1) 
        $discounted_amount = ($unit_price * $discounted_quantity) * 0.9;

        // add first non discounted price to total discount amount
        $total_discounted_price = $unit_price + $discounted_amount;

        // distribute discount over total quantity and get new unit price 
        $distributed_unit_discount = $total_discounted_price / $cart_item['quantity'];

        // set new unit price
        $cart_item['data']->set_price($distributed_unit_discount);
    }
```

**UPDATE 09-06-2018**

I got a strange behavior with logged in users, maybe depending on some conflict between plugins or with the theme I used (Avada): the discount applied twice so I had to prevent this adding this code to my function:

```
// Set the discounted price on 2nd item and
add_action('woocommerce_before_calculate_totals', 'add_discount_percentage_on_2nd_item', 999, 1);  

function add_discount_percentage_on_2nd_item($cart) {
    if (is_admin() && !defined('DOING_AJAX'))
        return;

if ( did_action( 'woocommerce_before_calculate_totals' ) >= 2 )
    return;
```

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> In cart object the only thing that you can really change and has an effect is **the active price**. 
>   **Changing regular or sale price in cart items has no effect.**

Try the following that will change the price from 2nd cart and beyond, and data will be passed correctly to Paypal:

```
// Calculate and save as custom cart item data the discounted price
add_filter('woocommerce_add_cart_item_data', 'add_custom_cart_item_data', 20, 3);

function add_custom_cart_item_data($cart_item_data, $product_id, $variation_id) {
    // HERE set the percentage rate to be applied to get the new price
    $percentage = 10; // 10%

    $_product_id = $variation_id > 0 ? $variation_id : $product_id;

    $product = wc_get_product($_product_id); // The WC_Product Object
    $base_price = (float) $product->get_price(); // Get the product active price

    // Save the calculated discounted price as custom cart item data
    $cart_item_data['discounted_price'] = $base_price * ( 100 - $percentage ) / 100;

    return $cart_item_data;
}

// Set the discounted price on 2nd item and
add_action('woocommerce_before_calculate_totals', 'add_discount_percentage_on_2nd_item', 20, 1);
function add_discount_percentage_on_2nd_item($cart) {
    if ( is_admin() && ! defined( 'DOING_AJAX' ) )
        return;

    if ( did_action( 'woocommerce_before_calculate_totals' ) >= 2 )
        return;

    $count = 0;

    // Loop through cart items
    foreach($cart->get_cart() as $cart_item) {
        $count++; // Increasing

        // On 2nd cart item or more set the calculated discounted price
        if ($count >= 2 && isset($cart_item['discounted_price']))
            $cart_item['data']->set_price($cart_item['discounted_price']);
    }
}
```

Code goes in function.php file of the active child theme (or active theme). Tested and works.

---

**Addition - Get a discount on all items, if cart content count is over 2.**

You will use the same first hooked function code than above.
You will replace the 2nd hooked function by the following:

```
// Set a discounted price on cart items when cart content count is over 2
add_action('woocommerce_before_calculate_totals', 'add_discount_percentage_on_2nd_item', 20, 1);
function add_discount_percentage_on_2nd_item($cart) {
    if ( is_admin() && ! defined( 'DOING_AJAX' ) )
        return;

    if ( did_action( 'woocommerce_before_calculate_totals' ) >= 2 )
        return;

    // Get the total items count
    $total_count = $cart->get_cart_contents_count();

    // if total count is below 2 we exit
    if( $total_count < 2 ) 
        return; // Exit

    // Loop through cart items
    foreach($cart->get_cart() as $cart_item) {

        // Set the calculated discounted price
        if (isset($cart_item['discounted_price']))
            $cart_item['data']->set_price($cart_item['discounted_price']);
    }
}
```

Code goes in function.php file of the active child theme (or active theme). It should works.

---

**Addition 2**

- Only first cart item is full price and next quantities are discounted for this first item)
- All newt cart items are discounted.

The code:

```
// Calculate and save as custom cart item data the discounted price
add_filter('woocommerce_add_cart_item_data', 'add_custom_cart_item_data', 20, 3);

function add_custom_cart_item_data($cart_item_data, $product_id, $variation_id) {
    // HERE set the percentage rate to be applied to get the new price
    $percentage = 10; // 10%

    $_product_id = $variation_id > 0 ? $variation_id : $product_id;

    $product = wc_get_product($_product_id); // The WC_Product Object
    $base_price = (float) $product->get_price(); // Get the product active price

    // Save the normal active product price as custom cart item data
    $cart_item_data['normal_price'] = $base_price;

    // Save the calculated discounted price as custom cart item data
    $cart_item_data['discounted_price'] = $base_price * ( 100 - $percentage ) / 100;

    return $cart_item_data;
}

// Set the discounted price on 2nd item and
add_action('woocommerce_before_calculate_totals', 'add_discount_percentage_on_2nd_item', 20, 1);

function add_discount_percentage_on_2nd_item($cart) {
    if (is_admin() && !defined('DOING_AJAX'))
        return;

    if ( did_action( 'woocommerce_before_calculate_totals' ) >= 2 )
        return; 

    // Initializing variables
    $count = 0;
    $first_item = true

    // Loop through cart items
    foreach($cart->get_cart() as $cart_item) {
        // 1. First cart item
        if ( isset($cart_item['discounted_price']) && isset($cart_item['normal_price']) && $first_item ){
            if( $cart_item['quantity'] > 1 ){
                $normal_price   = (float) $cart_item['normal_price'];
                $discount_price = (float) $cart_item['discounted_price'];
                $quantity       = (int) $cart_item['quantity'];

                // The first item is at full price and others at discounted price
                $cart_item['data']->set_price( $normal_price + ( $discount_price * ($quantity - 1) ) );
            }
            $first_item = false; // We switch it to false as it is the first cart item
        }
        // 2. All next items (at discounted price
        elseif ( isset($cart_item['discounted_price']) && ! $first_item ){
            // Set the discounted price
            $cart_item['data']->set_price($cart_item['discounted_price']);
        }
    }
}
```

Code goes in function.php file of the active child theme (or active theme). It should works.

Comment: Almost! I need to keep the first price non-discounted while the others must be discounted... that's why I created that complicated code I included in my edited question. I know it's a mess but the client requests are complicated, too.

Comment: If I can explain better: let's suppose I have **2 products** in my cart, **Product A - $30**, **Product B - $100**. I have **3 Product A** and **1 Product B**. My client needs to have this unit prices applied: **$30, $27, $27** (for **Product A**) and **$90** (for **Product B**). Hope it helps to clarify the problem. My code, don't know why, doesn't work properly. Thank you in advance for your help.

Comment: @YuriRefolo  I have added some more code again at the end (last time). It should work as your client wants.

Comment: Update: found a bug. If an user is logged in the discount is applied twice; if it's a guest, discount is applied right. I've tried to setup a counter outside the function with a global, but it won't work. Any ideas?

Comment: @YuriRefolo Sorry but I don't have that behavior… So there is something else that is interfering with that code. I have tested this code in both cases. I have a lot of similar answers and I use similar code for clients… So there is no bug.

Comment: No problem, I'll found the bug and I'll let you know. Thank you anyway for your help!

Answer (score 1):

payment gateway accepts "regular_price" & u have passed old price in it.
Try to set regular_price with new price variable, maybe it can work.

```html
//update _regular_price
$wpdb->update( 
    $wpdb->postmeta, 
    array( 'meta_value' => $default_product_price ), 
    array( 'meta_key' => '_regular_price' )
);
```

OR update the price in DB as per above code. That will surely help you.

Comment: still u get same price?

Comment: Yes, the same without discount